# change default "true" / "false" values of a checkbox after form submiting

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I would love to get rid of the standard "true" or "false" value of a checkbox when it is checked / unchecked and sent through a form... I wrote this little script but can't make it working, I am obviousliy new to code :)

In short: for a checked checkbox, instead of "true" I would love to have "Réservé" and instead of "false" I would love to have "Non Réservé"... is that possible ?

**jquery**

```
// wait for DOM to be ready
$(document).ready(function() {

  //define the variable for the checkboxes on the page
  var allCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[class=outsider]");

  //calls the append function on form submission
  $("#form-element").submit(function(event) {

    $(allCheckboxes).on('click', function() {

    $(this).val(this.checked ? Réservé : Non Réservé);

      alert($(this).val()); 
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="form-element">
  <input type="checkbox" class="outsider" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send" data-wait="Wait..." />
</form>
```

Comment: The fiddle works if you add `class="outsider"` to the checkbox.

Comment: You need to put `Reserve` and `Non Reserve` in quotes.

Comment: There's no default `true` and `false` value of a checkbox. The default value is `"on"`. The value doesn't change depending on whether the box is checked.

Comment: Remember, a checkbox is only sent to the server during submission if it's checked.

Comment: If you use `event.preventDefault()`, you're preventing the checkbox from changing from unchecked to checked.

Comment: So setting the value of a non-checked box is not very useful, since that value won't be submitted.

Comment: hi @Barmar, thank you so much for all the informations. I have created another codpen for you to have a look, should you have time.
Could something like that work ?

**jQuery**

`$(document).ready(function() {
    var allCheckboxes = $("input:checkbox[class=outsider]");
   $("#form-element").submit(function(event) {
    $(allCheckboxes).val(allCheckboxes.checked ? "Réservé" : "Non Réservé");
  });
});`
https://codepen.io/anthonysalamin/pen/wmyZwJ?editors=1010

Comment: `allCheckboxes.checked` makes no sense. `allCheckboxes` is a jQuery object, it doesn't have a `checked` property.

Comment: Post your code here, not comments or codepen. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to accomplish with this. Why don't you just use `value="Réservé"` in the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

The submiting function is fired when the form is submiting
so if you add an event on the checkbox in the submiting func it never gonna work

also barmar is right